# Tensorflow: Difference between tf.contrib.slim and tf.layers

Tags: tensorflow

When should I use tf.contrib.slim and when tf.layers?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and don't be discouraged by the downvotes. The first step is to read about how to post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

As defined in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib the contrib module contains "volatile or experimental code".

Generally speaking, the module `tf.contrib` contains contributed code. This code typically requires some additional tests and may encounter some significant changes before it is finally integrated into the TensorFlow core. In particular, this code is not supported by the Tensorflow team and may be modified or completely removed at any time without guarantees.

For this reason, in general I prefer to use `tf.layers` since it is more stable in terms of code support, but obviously some implementations in`tf.contrib` can be useful sometimes (i.e. when there are new kind of layers, optimizers etc. and you cannot or don't want to write them yourself, sometimes these libraries are quickly updated).